# What to do when you are living in very cold environment?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am on my way to a [shimla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimla), and as it is one of the coldest places of India.

Previously I lived in a warm environment of [southern india](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_India). What would be the correct way to live in a cold environment? I mean to say that would keeping our body warm every time will prevent us from loosing temperature. Or no expenditure of energy would be better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about physics

Comment: While solving the heat equation is physics, asking about how to keep warm in cold weather is far enough away from fundamental principles not to be an appropriate question on this site. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimla) the average winter temperature is 5°C, which is comparable to the UK. From personal experience wearing a pullover and coat is enough to deal with the UK winter. If you're going up into the mountains try Googling for ski wear or mountaineering wear.

Comment: so on while stackexchange site should i post it to get my answer

Comment: You could try http://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok i will surely delete this post

Comment: Can anyone migrate it to travel.SE? It seems right fit there.